# Remove referenced document from array Field list type in a document

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firebase called "community" and "users". All user records have a field "joinedCommunity" (a list of all joined communities).

I'm trying to figure a code that when a community is deleted, all user records are updated to only remove the community reference from "joinedCommunity" field list.

building this in flutterflow using custom action

onTap on a button in UI, the code is included as one of the actions before community document is deleted.

```
Future userRecordUpdate(DocumentReference community) async {
  final instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final batch = instance.batch();
  var collection = instance.collection('users');
  batch.update(collection, {
    "joinedCommunity": FieldValue.arrayRemove([community])
  });
  await batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code should work. Is it not updating the joindedCommunity fields?

Comment: the error I get is "The argument type 'CollectionReference <Map<String,dynamic>> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentReference<object?>'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code worked -

```
Future userRecordUpdate(DocumentReference community) async {
  final instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final batch = instance.batch();
  var collection = instance.collection('users');
  var snapshots =
      await collection.where("joinedCommunity", arrayContains: 
community).get();
  for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
    batch.update(doc.reference, {
      "joinedCommunity": FieldValue.arrayRemove([community])
    });
  }
  await batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `CollectionReference`, when what you want is a `DocumentReference`. As per the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch-class.html), `WriteBatch.update` only works on a `DocumentReference`.

I have a few suggestions:

1. Try updating the field without using a WriteBatch. Use a for loop and a regular `DocumentReference.update()` call.
2. Then, update your code to use a `WriteBatch` to update the field. Also, keep in mind a batch is limited to 500 operations.
3. Finally, consider the security implications of allowing a client to be able to update any User document. You should probably update your security rules so that a user document can only be modified by that user. This code is probably something that should run in a Firebase Cloud Function that gets triggered whenever a community document is deleted.